# ¿Con qué reemplazar utf8_decode en PHP 8?

Tags: php, deprecated

Con la llegada de php 8 alguna funciones no están disponibles, como utf8_decode.

¿Que se usa en su lugar?,

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ma atrevería a decir que es una función que no necesitas, y no me refiero a PHP 8, incluso antes, es una función de la que podías prescindir totalmente si configurabas correctamente tu entorno en los diferentes niveles. [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967) y en algunos comentarios he intentado arrojar luz sobre esto, porque en el pasado había una tendencia a usar este tipo de funciones, pasando por ella cada dato, lo cual era absurdo. Imagina un contexto de BD donde tienes que pasar caaaada valor de cada columna por esa función, en vez de configurar bien el entorno.

Comment: y en el caso que no este bien configurado? por ejemplo importar una base de datos, o insertar registros desde un txt , etc... ¿como puedo saber como está codificada la tabla? para usar mb_convert_encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar mb_convert_encoding (aunque yo tengo problemas para detectar el tercer parametro de esta función).

Comment: publique un pseudocodigo arriba para que puedas detectar el encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Detéctalo así:

```
   private function devArryUTF8() {
    return array(
        "UCS-4",
        "UCS-4BE",
        "UCS-4LE",
        "UCS-2",
        "UCS-2BE",
        "UCS-2LE",
        "UTF-32",
        "UTF-32BE",
        "UTF-32LE",
        "UTF-16",
        "UTF-16BE",
        "UTF-16LE",
        "UTF-7",
        "UTF7-IMAP",
        "UTF-8",
        "ASCII",
        "EUC-JP",
        "SJIS",
        "eucJP-win",
        "SJIS-win",
        "ISO-2022-JP",
        "ISO-2022-JP-MS",
        "CP932",
        "CP51932",
        "SJIS-mac",
        "SJIS-DOCOMO",
        "SJIS-KDDI",
        "SJIS-SOFTBANK",
        "UTF-8-DOCOMO",
        "UTF-8-Mobile#KDDI-A",
        "UTF-8-KDDI",
        "UTF-8-SOFTBANK",
        "ISO-2022-JP-KDDI",
        "JIS",
        "JIS-ms",
        "CP50220",
        "CP50220raw",
        "CP50221",
        "CP50222",
        "ISO-8859-1",
        "ISO-8859-2",
        "ISO-8859-3",
        "ISO-8859-4",
        "ISO-8859-5",
        "ISO-8859-6",
        "ISO-8859-7",
        "ISO-8859-8",
        "ISO-8859-9",
        "ISO-8859-10",
        "ISO-8859-13",
        "ISO-8859-14",
        "ISO-8859-15",
        "ISO-8859-16",
        "byte2be",
        "byte2le",
        "byte4be",
        "byte4le",
        "BASE64",
        "HTML",
        "7bit",
        "8bit",
        "EUC-CN",
        "CP936",
        "GB18030",
        "HZ",
        "EUC-TW",
        "CP950",
        "BIG-5",
        "EUC-KR",
        "CP949",
        "ISO-2022-KR",
        "CP1251",
        "CP1252",
        "IBM866",
        "KOI8-R",
        "KOI8-U",
        "ArmSCII8"
    );
}
```

function:
$a = $this->devArryUTF8();

```
        // for ($i=0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
        //     for ($y=0; $y < count($a); $y++) {
        //         $atmp = array(
        //             'nombre' => $a[$i].' -> '.$a[$y].' = '.mb_convert_encoding($string, $a[$i], $a[$y])
        //         );
        //         array_push($adev, $atmp);
        //     }
        // }
```

al imprimir $adev, sabrás cual es el encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Sería así:

```
mb_convert_encoding($string, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
```